# Python dictionary of sets in SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, dictionary, sqlite

I have a dictionary in Python where the keys are integers and the values sets of integers. Considering the potential size (millions of key-value pairs, where a set can contain from 1 to several hundreds of integers), I would like to store it in a SQL (?) database, rather than serialize it with pickle to store it and load it back in whenever I need it.

From reading around I see two potential ways to do this, both with its downsides:

- **Serialize the sets and store them as BLOBs:** So I would get an SQL with two columns, the first column are the keys of the dictionary as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the second column are the BLOBS, containing a set of integers.
  Downside: Not able to alter sets anymore without loading the complete BLOB in, and after adding a value to it, serialize it back and insert it back to the database as a BLOB.
- **Add a unique key for each element of each set:** I would get two columns, one with the keys (which are now key_dictionary + index element of set/list), one with one integer value in each row. I'd now be able to add values to a "set" without having to load the whole set into python. I would have to put more work in keeping track of all the keys.

In addition, once the database is complete, I will always need sets as a whole, so idea 1 seems to be faster? If I query for all in primary keys BETWEEN certain values, or LIKE certain values, to obtain my whole set in system 2, will the SQL database (sqlite) still work as a hashtable? Or will it linearly search for all values that fit my BETWEEN or LIKE search?

Overall, what's the best way to tackle this problem? Obviously, if there's a completely different 3rd way that solves my problems naturally, feel free to suggest it! (haven't found any other solution by searching around)

I'm kind of new to Python and especially to databases, so let me know if my question isn't clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second answer is *nearly* what I would recommend. What I would do is have three columns:

- Set ID
- Key
- Value

I would then create a composite primary key on the Set ID and Key which guarantees that the combination is unique:

```
CREATE TABLE something (
  set, 
  key, 
  value, 
  PRIMARY KEY (set, key)
);
```

You can now add a value straight into a particular set (Or update a key in a set) and select all keys in a set.

This being said, your first strategy would be more optimal for read-heavy workloads as the size of the indexes would be smaller.

> will the SQL database (sqlite) still work as a hashtable?

SQL databases tend *not* to use hashtables. Nor do they usually do a sequential lookup. What they do is usually create an index (Which tends to be some kind of tree, e.g. a B-tree) which allows for range lookups (e.g. where you don't know exactly what keys you're looking for).

Comment: Thanks! The PRIMARY KEY (set, key) makes a lot of sense, definitely have to dig deeper into how to use databases.  

A B tree has a time complexity of O(log(n)), which is worse than the O(1) I thought a hash table in general has, and which a dictionary in python has (?). Any way of using a database in a way taking an item out of it does have O(1)?

Comment: O(log(n)) is pretty damn efficient and should not be an issue unless you got into the billions/trillions of rows range. That's also only for random access lookups. Any kind of range lookup in a hashtable is O(n) minimum while in a SQL index it'll be O(k) (Proportional to the number you're querying rather than the whole dataset).

Comment: If you needed to scale further than that then you would need to look into something like a Key-Value database such as Couchbase or Redis which *are* based on hashtables. The downside of this is looking up all records in say a set is difficult and would require it's own index which are featured in some KV databases.

Comment: Ok, thanks, clarifies a lot! The reason I would like to use a real hashtable is because the original algorithm (I'm building my own Shazam as a hobby probject) is constructed around the idea. 

Every second of recording a song I need to take out a dozen of full sets out of the database of probably around a million different sets, but I can imagine you're right a O(log(n)) or O(1) is not really going to make the difference yet, so I'll give your idea a try!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. What I *would* recommend in this instance is making sure you abstract the code sufficiently that you can switch backends with ease.

e.g. encapsulate it in a class https://gist.github.com/Chippiewill/b3e1bddb3c20f9e76477b53c16c77a67

That way you can even try different implementations and compare them. If performance is an issue always measure before making a decision!

Comment: Is there any way to not have to keep track of the key myself? I don't care about accessing specific values in a set, I just want to be able to add values to a set or extract the whole set. I had the impression sqlite would assign a unique value to key out of itself if I insert (set,value), but instead it makes it NULL I think, so I can't insert (set1,value1) and (set1,value2) after each other, the composite key isn't unique... If I use a NOT NULL table, it tells me I can't insert (set1,value1) at all, I have to give it a key too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, in this case it's not really key-value per-se. You just have a bunch of sets. I would switch to a table with 3 columns: id, set, value. ID should be the primary index, you can use something like auto increment to do it automatically. You can then create a secondary index on the set and you should be able to pull everything from that set and insert straight into that set (Something like 'INSERT INTO table (set, value) VALUES ($set_id, $value')

Comment: But this would mean I wouldn't be able to use one single id anymore to pull out all the elements of a certain set? Making only the ID the primary index means every single value will have a different ID. Or you mean my middle column will have a fixed value for all the elements of the same set? Without it being an index/key, won't searching for all the elements of a certain set become slow?

Thanks for the answers btw!

Comment: You can create a secondary index (But not unique) on the set ID which will make lookups efficient ('CREATE INDEX set_index ON table(set)')